# Uber Login Not Working Correctly

Tags: ios, swift, uber-api

I am having problems getting the uber login to work in my ios app. I have tried both using the loginButton and using the loginManager by itself.

When using the loginManager by itself, and using the .native loginType, I am receiving "Error Domain=com.uber.rides-ios-sdk.ridesAuthenticationError Code=13"

When attempting to use the loginButton, it is never even displayed. I get a huge printout in the console (shown in picture below. Was having trouble getting pasted text to show up correctly)

[debug console errors after trying to add login button subview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBsvB.jpg)

I have tried creating a new project from scratch and am seeing the same behavior with both the loginButton and loginManager (after modifying the App Signature to match the newly created project). I am using Xcode 9, Swift 4.0, and UberRides ios SDK 0.7.0

I have checked the "profile" General Scope in the developer dashboard, and have added my bundle identifier under the App Signatures section for iOS

Here is the information I've added to my Info.plist:

```
<key>UberClientID</key>
<string>[removed]</string>
<key>UberDisplayName</key>
<string>[removed]</string>
<key>UberServerToken</key>
<string>[removed]</string>
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>uber</string>
    <string>uberauth</string>
</array>
<key>UberCallbackURIs</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UberCallbackURIType</key>
        <string>Native</string>
        <key>URIString</key>
        <string>[removed bundle identifier]://oauth/consumer</string>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>[removed bundle identifier]</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Here's my code for the loginButton (I've also made the view controller I'm implementing this code in the LoginButtonDelegate and have added the two necessary functions (didLogoutWithSuccess and didCompleteLoginWithToken) to allow the view controller to act as a delegate)

```
    let scopes: [RidesScope] = [.profile]
    let loginManager = LoginManager(loginType: .native)
    let loginButton = LoginButton(frame: CGRect.zero, scopes: scopes, loginManager: loginManager)
    loginButton.presentingViewController = self
    loginButton.delegate = self
    loginButton.center = self.view.center
    self.view.addSubview(loginButton)
```

Here's the code I was using to attempt to use the login manager (I've since commented this out while trying to implement the login button):

```
        let loginManager = LoginManager(loginType: .native)
        loginManager.login(requestedScopes:[RidesScope.profile], presentingViewController: self, completion: { accessToken, error in
            // Completion block. If accessToken is non-nil, you’re good to go
            // Otherwise, error.code corresponds to the RidesAuthenticationErrorType that occured

            let ridesClient = RidesClient()
            ridesClient.fetchUserProfile(completion: {profile, response in
                if let error = response.error{
                    // handle error
                    print(error.code)
                }
                if let profile = profile{
                    // do something with profile

                }
            })

        })
```

Please let me know if you need any additional info. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I had an epiphany after posting this and looked back over the code and noticed that the example used CGRect.zero. I used CGRect(x: 0, y:0, width: 100, height: 100) and then the button appeared in view and seemed to work as expected when tapped on... Not sure why the example would make a button with no size... I would still like to understand why the loginManager is not working correctly, if possible. Thanks!

Comment: I think I may have figured it out. In my dashboard, I used an arbitrary URI for a URL located on my server (because that is how the example is formatted: https://www.yourapp.com/redirect_uri). It was not clear to me that this should match the [bundle_id]://oauth/consumer format... Stupid mistake on my part, but in my opinion, the default description should be more clear in the dashboard (maybe something like "https://www.yourapp.com/redirect_uri OR [bundle_id]://oauth/consumer for applications")

Comment: Thanks Max. Glad you figured it out! I'm aware of the button size issue and will fix it. We'll also making an effort to make the OAuth instructions more clear in the dashboard, but for now the SDK readme is the source of truth :)